# AngularJS - hide/show div if date is within last 6 months

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, angular-filters, ng-hide

I have an `ng-repeat` that displays a list of dates, and information about purchases on that dates.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    <p>
        {{ data.purchasedOn.substring(6, data.purchasedOn.length - 2) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        {{ data.purchaseDescription }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Which displays:

```
01/02/2013
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"

10/04/2014
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"

02/08/2014
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"

13/06/2014
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"

19/02/2013
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
```

How can i only show the `{{ data.purchaseDescription }}` when `purchasedOn` is within the last 6 months from the current month?

Comment: I would implement a custom filter on ng-repeat.

Comment: @CodeHater - do you have an example?

Comment: Added to my answer below with an example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to show purchasedOn but not the description, you could use a function like [this one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648392/javascript-get-a-dateobject-six-months-previous-from-another-date-object) to determine a date 6 months prior.

```
function addMonths(date, months) {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
  return date;
}
```

Then define a function to get a boolean show/hide value:

```
function shouldHide(purchasedOn){
    var purchaseDate = Date.parse(purchasedOn);
    var sixMonthsAgo = addMonths(new Date(), -6); 
    var hide = purchaseDate < sixMonthsAgo ? true : false;
    return hide;
}
```

Now you can just use your function in an ng-hide in your `<p>` element

```
<p ng-hide={{shouldHide(data.purchasedOn)}}>
    {{ data.purchaseDescription }}
</p>
```

**EDIT**
If you do just want to hide the entire element, you could make a filter function like this:

```
$scope.filterOldDates = function(date)
{
    if(shouldHide(date)){
        return false; 
    }
    return true; 
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData | filterOldDates">
```