# Angular 7/ Typescript Hide a Div based on time created

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have div element, i want to hide it when its time created is more than 6 months ago. How to implement this in typescript and angular 7

[AngularJS - hide/show div if date is within last 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198680/angularjs-hide-show-div-if-date-is-within-last-6-months/63894679#63894679)

I had tried like this it thorws error Property 'getMonth' does not exist on type 'DateConstructor'
HTML:

```
 <div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTime>six_month_before_date">
<!-Only then display data-->
</div>
```

Typescript

```
      public date = new Date() ;
  public six_month_before_date= this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6); 


     private getRequestDuration(request) {
    let createdDate = new Date(request.createTime);
    let timeInMilliSeconds = this.currentDate.getTime() - 
     createdDate.getTime();
    let seconds = timeInMilliSeconds / 1000;
    let minutes = seconds / 60;
    let hours = minutes / 60 + 5; // FIXME: EST Offset
    hours = hours > 0 ? hours : 0; // FIXME: Hack to address time-stamp conversions / daylight savings time
    let days = hours / 24;
    return (days > 0 ? Math.floor(days) + ' days, ' : '') + Math.floor(hours % 24) + ' hours';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to TypeScript nor Angular itself, the method `getMonth` is not static so you can't execute by its class name, you need to use an instance:

```
private getRequestDuration(request) {
    let six_month_before_date = new Date();
    six_month_before_date.setMonth(six_month_before_date.getMonth() - 6);// minus six month
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** A possible solution for your problem would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="request" *ngIf="createTime > six_month_before_date">
```

**TypeScript**

```
@Component({ ... })
export class YourClassComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    createTime: Date;
    six_month_before_date: Date;

    ngOnInit() {
        const request = await doYourRequestHere();
        const duration = getRequestDuration(request); // Not being used now but may be needed somewhere else
        this.createTime = new Date(request.createTime);
        this.six_month_before_date = this.getSixMonthBeforeDate();
    }

    private getSixMonthBeforeDate() {
        const currentDate = new Date(); 
        currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 6);
        return currentDate;
    }

    private getRequestDuration(request) {
        let createdDate = new Date(request.createTime);
        let timeInMilliSeconds = this.six_month_before_date.getTime() - 
        createdDate.getTime();
        let seconds = timeInMilliSeconds / 1000;
        let minutes = seconds / 60;
        let hours = minutes / 60 + 5; // FIXME: EST Offset
        hours = hours > 0 ? hours : 0; // FIXME: Hack to address time-stamp conversions / daylight savings time
        let days = hours / 24;
        return (days > 0 ? Math.floor(days) + ' days, ' : '') + Math.floor(hours % 24) + ' hours';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David is the ng If condition correct ?                                                                                <div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTime>six_month_before_date"> it hides everthing rite now, irrespective if time created

Comment: Not quite, `request.createTime` is a `string`, correct? You need to use the `Date` instances for the comparison.

Comment: <div class="request"  *ngIf="createdDate> six_month_before_date"> is this correct

Comment: Sure, just share the relevant part of your component code. Assuming `createdDate` and `six_month_before_date` are `Date` types and are available to the template, yes, it is valid.

Comment: Hi David                                                                                                                
  public date = new Date() ;
  public six_month_before_date= this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6);         <div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTime>six_month_before_date">

</div>                                                                                                                           this is not working

Comment: Don't use the comments, edit your question with the component code (TypeScript) so I can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hi David updated the question can you provide me proper ngIf condition please

Comment: I added an example but I had to make some assumptions. Take a loot at it :)

Comment: david join this meeting https://us04web.zoom.us/j/75632225672?pwd=VnRIdy9IaCtBSUtFVVVaaWZES1JwQT09